# TKinter update scrolledText

Tags: python, tkinter

On create window, `tkinter.scrolledtext` look up for `SearchIP()` to insert but never update layout. When I have different input for `SearchIP()` method never show up. It only shows the initial value.

Note: I added a couple of print statements to watch if `SearchIP()` returns the right thing, which is the case, for example for 'www.google.com' it prints '216.58.192.4', but this value never shows up in ScrolledText.

[image: image of output]

```
import socket
try:
    # for Python2
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ScrolledText as tkst
except ImportError:
    # for Python3
    import tkinter as tk
    import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkst

global Filename

root = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(root,width=100)
label = Label(root,text="http://")
label.grid(row=0,column=0)
entryVar = tk.StringVar()
entry = Entry(root,width=50,textvariable=entryVar)
entry.grid(row='0',column='1',columnspan=8)

def SearchIP():
  print(entryVar.get())
  add = str(entryVar.get())
  ip_a = socket.gethostbyname(add)
  print(str(ip_a))
  return str(ip_a);

button1 = Button(root, text="Search IP", command=SearchIP)
button1.grid(row=1, column=0)
button2 = Button(root, text="DNS Recon")
button2.grid(row=1, column=1)
button3 = Button(root, text="Port Scanner")
button3.grid(row=1, column=2)
button4 = Button(root, text="Web Crawl")
button4.grid(row=1, column=3)
button5 = Button(root, text="Email Gathering")
button5.grid(row=1, column=4)
frame.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=30, rowspan=30)
edit_space = tkst.ScrolledText(
    master = frame,
    wrap   = 'word',  # wrap text at full words only
    width  = 45,      # characters
    height = 10,      # text lines
     # background color of edit area
)
# the padx/pady space will form a frame
edit_space.pack(fill='both', expand=True, padx=8, pady=8)
root.title("E-Z Security Audting")
root.resizable(True, True)
edit_space.insert('insert', SearchIP())

root.mainloop()
```

I also tried to modify the `SearchIP()` method and remove the return statement, but then I got this error:

```
  File "C:/Users/kero/Desktop/Robert_HodgesKeroles_Hakeem_secproject/secproject/new‌​User_Interface.py", line 50, in <module>
    edit_space.insert('insert', SearchIP())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2986, in insert
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'insert', index, chars) + args)`
```

SearchIP after modification

```
def  SearchIP():
    add = str(entryVar.get())
    ip_a= socket.gethostbyname(add)
```

Comment: Using `return` in `SearchIP` is useless. Button call `SearchIP` but it can't use returned value.

Comment: now code is colored so I see you use `SearchIP()` not only with `command` and you need `return`.

Comment: You should use `insert()` inside `SearchIP()`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `insert()` inside `SearchIP()`

```
import socket

try:
  # for Python2
  import Tkinter as tk
  import ScrolledText as tkst
except ImportError:
  # for Python3
  import tkinter as tk
  import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkst

# --- functions ---

def SearchIP():
    add = entryVar.get()
    ip_a = socket.gethostbyname(add)
    edit_space.insert('insert', ip_a + "\n")

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

root.title("E-Z Security Audting")
root.resizable(True, True)

frame = tk.Frame(root, width=100)
frame.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=30, rowspan=30)

label = tk.Label(root, text="http://")
label.grid(row=0, column=0)

entryVar = tk.StringVar()
entry = tk.Entry(root, width=50, textvariable=entryVar)
entry.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=8)

button1 = tk.Button(root, text="Search IP", command=SearchIP)
button1.grid(row=1, column=0)

button2 = tk.Button(root, text="DNS Recon")
button2.grid(row=1, column=1)

button3 = tk.Button(root, text="Port Scanner")
button3.grid(row=1, column=2)

button4 = tk.Button(root, text="Web Crawl")
button4.grid(row=1, column=3)

button5 = tk.Button(root, text="Email Gathering")
button5.grid(row=1, column=4)

edit_space = tkst.ScrolledText(
    master=frame,
    wrap='word',  # wrap text at full words only
    width=45,      # characters
    height=10,      # text lines
     # background color of edit area
)
edit_space.pack(fill='both', expand=True, padx=8, pady=8)

root.mainloop()
```